# AzureClient `onProgress' callback giving file upload status, but as soon as we call the api to fetch files it's not reflecting that uploaded file

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk

I came across some weird behavior.
I have to upload file to azure storage and I am using [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob) to upload.

`OnProgress` callback is getting completed means my file is uploaded successfully.
But as soon as I call, azure api to fetch files again it's not returning that latest uploaded file.

If I am calling fetch api in `setInterval` then in some of the call I am getting this file.

So is it related to concurrency at azure or I am doing something wrong here?

```
const sassUrl = generateSasUrl() // to generate sasUrl
const azureClient = new ContainerClient(sassUrl).getBlobClient(fileName)

azureClient.uploadData(file , {
    onProgress: ({loadedBytes}) => {
       const isUploaded = loadedBytes === fileSize;
          if(isUploaded){
            fetchAzureFiles()
          }

     }  
})


async function fetchAzureFiles(){
 const url = `https://${accoutnName}/blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}`;
 
 const containerClient = new ContainerClient(containerUrl, new ManagedIdentityCredential(clientId, UAMI_CLient_id));
 
 const files = await containerClient.listAdlsFiles();
 return files



 

}
```

Comment: Can you share your code in the question?

Comment: Sure will add.. But it's more about knowning flow

Comment: Please edit your question and include code for `fetchAzureFiles()` function.

Comment: @GauravMantri  added code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way i'm able to call, azure api to fetch files again, below code will call the Azure API to fetch files again after uploading a file to the container. This is because the `fetchAzureFiles` function is called within the `uploadFileToAzureStorage` function after the file has been uploaded. The `fetchAzureFiles` function retrieves the list of files in the container, which includes the newly uploaded file.

```
const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } =  require("@azure/storage-blob");

const  accountName  =  "accountName";
const  accountKey  =  "accountKey";
const  containerName  =  "containerName";
const  fileName  =  "example.txt";
const  filePath  =  "./example.txt"; // Adjust the path based on the location of your file

async  function  uploadFileToAzureStorage() {

const  sharedKeyCredential  =  new  StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
const  blobServiceClient  =  new  BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`, sharedKeyCredential);
const  containerClient  =  blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const  blockBlobClient  =  containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(fileName);

try {

await  blockBlobClient.uploadFile(filePath);

console.log("File uploaded successfully.");

const  fileList  =  await  fetchAzureFiles();

console.log("Files in the container:", fileList);

} catch (error) {
console.error("Error uploading file:", error.message);
}
}

async  function  fetchAzureFiles() {

const  sharedKeyCredential  =  new  StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
const  blobServiceClient  =  new  BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`, sharedKeyCredential);

const  containerClient  =  blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  

const  files  = [];
try {
let  marker  =  undefined;
do {
const  response  =  await  containerClient.listBlobFlatSegment(marker);
marker  =  response.nextMarker;
for (const  blob  of  response.segment.blobItems) {
files.push(blob.name);
}
} while (marker);
return  files;
} catch (error) {
console.error("Error fetching Azure files:", error.message);
throw  error;
}
}

uploadFileToAzureStorage();
```

**Result**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks will refer this.. Will try in my code as well.
Again thanks for detail explanation